# Floating in body

Tags: css

i don't understand, why my floating doesn't work. There is the [site](http://lab.gio.lt) - and as you can see, the floating doesn't want to work. What is the problem with it?

Comment: Hi. sorry, where you want this block to be ? as I can see it in the right corner of container

Comment: Remove the blocks with `clear: both`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. It's floating right in the context of it's parent which is `<div id="content">`.
You need to put it (in HTML code) before the `<div class="side_bar">` which is floating left, like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="news_block">
        the floating to the right side - don't want to work
    </div>
    <div class="side_bar">
        sidebar
    </div>
</div>
```

OR, if for example your scripts need that, you want to wrap everything you want on the left side to the side_bar DIV, which is the only one which has the CSS to float on the left. Maybe you haven't noticed it, but you have:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="side_bar"> <!-- floats left -->
        sidebar
    </div>
    <div> facebook thing </div> <!-- doesn't float -->
    <div> ads </div> <!-- doesn't float -->
    <div> whatever </div> <!-- doesn't float -->
    <div class="news_block"> <!-- floats right-->
        the floating to the right side - don't want to work
    </div>
</div>
```

You can't expect the two DIVs which have `float` defined to float correctly, when you have non-floating element in between them.

Comment: sorry, i didn't get that :(